# symfony 2 and doctrine, selecting rows table by number of joned records from another table

Tags: sql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

basically i have a table1 table and tabl2 table.

relation one to many

So i'm trying to make a select like

```
$em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('t1')
            ->from('AcmeAppBundle:Table1', 't1')
            ->orderBy('t1.id', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

so i need the same query but i need the order to be by number of records from table2
the relation is set in the entity something like

```
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Table2", mappedBy="something")
```

in raw query it looks like

```
SELECT table1.*  FROM table1 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id
                                group by (table2.table1_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb
    ->select('t1')
    ->from('AcmeAppBundle:Table1', 't1')
    ->leftJoin('BLABLABundle:BlaEntity', 't2', 'WITH', 't1.id = t2.table1_id')
    ->orderBy('t1.id', 'DESC')
    ->groupBy('t2.table1_id');

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

   $qb
    ->select('count(t2.id) count')
    ->from('AcmeAppBundle:Table1', 't1')
    ->join('AcmeAppBundle:Table1', 't2', 'WITH', 't1.id = t2.table1_id')
    ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
    ->groupBy('t1.id');
```

Somethins like this. But not tested.

Answer (score 0):

This would order the result by number of records from table2:

```
    $queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('t1, COUNT(t2.id) AS myCount')
            ->from('AcmeAppBundle:Table1', 't1')
            ->leftJoin('t1.fields', 't2') //fields is the one to many field name for the target entity AcmeAppBundle:Table2
            ->groupBy('t1.id')
            ->orderBy('myCount', 'DESC');
    $result = $queryBuilder
                    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```